# Where to use the dependency injection container in Zend/Zend 2

Tags: zend-framework, dependency-injection, zend-framework2

This relates to DI as much as it relates to the Zend framework.  My question is about where to use the DI container.  Should it only every be used durring bootstrap for initialization leaving the rest of the application ignorant of existence?  Or is it good practice to pass it to controllers, models, helpers, etc to be used there if needed?  What about Zend 2?

Comment: A DI Container should be encapsulated in a Composition Root: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx

Answer (score 5):

As it relates to dependency injection in general, that is something you should be practicing if you are attempting to write SOLID code.  I have two articles I've written on the subject of Dependency Injection as it relates to the background knowledge (I think) developers should have before jumping directly into code that uses a DiC:

http://ralphschindler.com/2011/05/18/learning-about-dependency-injection-and-php

I've also compiled some examples of how to use Zend\Di that is a DiC component in the ZF2 codebase:

https://github.com/ralphschindler/Zend_DI-Examples/

Another point, I'd like to make ... Once you start passing the DiC as a dependency into controllers, models etc ... your DiC actually becomes a Service Locator at that point.  This is perfectly acceptable, but you need to be aware up front that using a Service Locator would/should have been part of your design goals.

The next beta cycle of ZF2 will probably better address how Di and Service Locators are used through modules, controllers and how dependencies are pushed into things like helpers and models.  So keep an eye out for that.

Hope that gets you started.

Answer (score 0):

I have been reading some of the answers. First, as far as I know, it is currently not built in with the Zend framework < ver 2 to have the Dependency Injection Container do its work in the "composition root".

Hence, your best bet would be a service locator as mentioned already here. I have come up with a Zend framework application setup to do just that. Check it out over [here](https://github.com/jeunito/zf-doctrine2-symfonydi).

In a nutshell, [what it does](http://jeunito.me/zf1-11-doctrine-2-symfony-di-integration/) is

1. Bootstrap Symfony Dependency Injection in the Zend Application Bootstrap class
2. Get the container from 1 in a Zend controller where you can use it to retrieve your services